# Netbeans 8.0 Modify installed plugin

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

I have downloaded the https://github.com/jonathanlermitage/tikione-jacocoverage/ plugin and it seems quite decent, but there is one thing that is bugging me, visualized here:

[image]

I am fine with the little glyphs on the left hand side of the lines which indicate for example git status.
However I *strongly* dislike my whole lines being colored.

I know which XML files might be the culprit, found in https://github.com/jonathanlermitage/tikione-jacocoverage/tree/master/tikione-jacocoverage-plugin/src/fr/tikione/jacocoverage/plugin/resources.

So the following questions:

1. Where are the plugins installed in Netbeans?
2. How can I modify XML files in the plugins?

Bonus for showing how to either fully remove the line color and add a little glyph to the left (or right) or to make the line color a very very white green or red.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin is installed by default into userdir - http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir - unless you asked to install it into installation directory where the rest of installation is created by installer.

You can try to update the resource in .jar file under modules folder. There can be some checksums. If it does not work you can try to clone the repository, patch the source and build `nbm` target. It will generate `.nbm` file that you can manually install as a plugin in 'downloaded' tab in plugin manager.

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm aware, what you are specifying is already how netbeans does this by default:

[image]

However, you can still try looking under `Options>Fonts & Colors>Highlighting`